# Is there any Hashable list datatype?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, big-o

Maybe this is a very noob question.

The complexity of looking for an element from a list is O(n) (if the list is sorted it can be done in O(log n) which is way better).

However the complexity of doing the same operation in a dictionary is O(1) (because keys in a dictionary are hashable).

Then, if my data is hashable (integers, strings), I could store my data as dictionary keys just to have this speed boost when looking if an element is in the dictionary.

However a dictionary is a pair key/value, and I just want to use it as a list, so I just need keys without values.

Of course I can create a dict with empty values for each key, but I'm wondering, does something else already exist to do what I'm suggesting?

If I do this it takes O(1)

```
my_dict = {2:[], 8:[], 3:[], 4:[]}
3 in my_dict
```

If I use a list it takes O(n):

```
my_list = [2,8,3,4]
`3 in my_list`
```

I want something like

```
my_hashable_list = [2,8,3,4]
3 in my_hashable_list()   # so it takes O(1)
```

Does such a datatype exist?

Comment: There is a `set`.

Comment: The question is misleading because you don't actually want a hashable list - you're actually looking for a data structure that hashes its elements.

Comment: @Rawing Thank you. This is exactly why I *thought* OP was looking for a `frozenset` at first.

Comment: @rawing well I just want a list of elements, but to be able to hash them, so I think I actually want a hashable list right? Otherwise maybe I misunderstand what a hashable list would be.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki You don't actually care if _the list itself_ is hashable, so it's misleading to call it "hashable list". You're looking for a data structure that efficiently stores hashable elements - a `set`.